# Ordinate of zeros of zeta Riemann function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

In the book: Multiplicative Number Theory, Davenport, we see that there is a bound for ordinates of zeros of zeta Riemann function ($s=\beta+i\gamma$ is zero of zeta function)
[image]

My question is that how can we prove that $\gamma_1$ (the smallest positive $\gamma$ among zeros of zeta function) is bigger or equal to 6.5, i.e. $\gamma_1>=6.5$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it is known that the first $\gamma$ is between $14$ and $15$ -the Riemann Siegel approximation of the Hardy function should give this easily (Edwards book chapter 6 gives an overview of early computations, while chapter 7 page 157 gives a simple argument for the first zero being near $t=14.5$ as the Riemann Siegel main term is zero there)

Comment: Thank you for this comment!